# Return to a View from Controller after an Api call - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, api, rest, authentication, laravel-8

So guys,

I have an app that needs to login.
After login and getting the API and token, it has to redirect to a dashboard, but unfortunately, I can't make it to a dashboard view.

I try to find answers on the forum but can't find one that suits my code.

Here is my **api.php**

```
Route::post('/login', App\Http\Controllers\api\LoginController::class)->name('login');
```

my **web.php**

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [Controller::class, 'dashboard']);
```

my **LoginController**

```
    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        //set validation
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email'     => 'required',
            'password'  => 'required'
        ]);
    //if validation fails
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
    }

    //get credentials from request
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    //if auth failed
    if(!$token = auth()->guard('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Email atau Password Anda salah'
        ], 401);
    }

    //if auth success
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'user'    => auth()->guard('api')->user(),    
        'token'   => $token   
    ], 200);
}
```

my **AuthController** :

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request){
        $email = $request->input("email");
        $password = $request->input("password");

        $request = Request::create('http://localhost:8000/api/login', 'POST',[
                'name'=>$email,
                'password'=>$password,
            ]);

    $response = json_decode(Route::dispatch($request)->getContent());

    // echo($response->success);
    if($response->success == 1 || true){
        return redirect()->route('dashboard',["response"=>$response]);
    }else{
        return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller.php** where `dashboard` route is defined:

```
public function dashboard() 
    {
        return view('dashboard', [
            "title" => "Dashboard",
        ]);
    }
```

if I'm using this code, the error I get is:

> Route [dashboard] not defined.

but if I'm not using `return redirect` and use `return view` instead. I can go to my dashboard, but the URL is `localhost:8000\auth\login` which is not what I want.

is there any suggestion so I can get my view on Dashboard?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You haven't named your dashboard route. Try this for your `web.php`: `Route::get('/dashboard', [Controller::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');`

Comment: Also make sure that the `/dashboard` route is available when you test in the browser

Comment: okay, mate @Laisender now the route dashboard is defined. but now the `$response` variable in my view is undefined :|

PS: I edited my question, adding my dashboard route from `Controller.php`

Comment: Well maybe your `dashboard` route doesn't know it is supposed to receive that `$response` variable. Try changing your `Controller.php` to `public function dashboard($response = null) { if($response == null) { dd('response was empty'); } else { dd($response); }} ` to see that you are receiving the parameter.

Comment: ahhhh, its `^ "response was empty"` - but I'm sure that my API is fine because now the URL is change to `ocalhost:8000/dashboard?response%5Bsuccess%5D=1&response%5Buser%5D%5Bid%5D=1&response%5Buser%5D%5Bname%5D=...` and so on @Laisender